# After I change my targetSDKversion to 23, app Screen appear white screen

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm developing android app and our boss want to upgrade the app to work on Android 6.0. So i upgrade the Build SDK target to SDK 6.0 and then I changed my android:targetSdkVersion to 23 in Manifest file. And then the app appear only white screen and nothing happened. Why is that happening? If I re-change android:targetSdkVersion to 22 then it's working. But permission request need for Android OS 6 huh? That's why i need to change android:targetSdkVersion to 23. Please guide me. As for addition, I've to develop that app with Eclipse. The boss don't want to use Android Studio. Please guide me with Eclipse solving. Thanks you very much.

Comment: `Please guide me with Eclipse solving` this is unclear, and vague. what have you tried that did not work?

Comment: You are way too far from android new updates. Eclipse is no more supported by Android and Now Android O dev preview is launched. Check if you asked runtime permission or not? https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en this will help.

Comment: check if it is crashing due to runtime permissions

Comment: @sravs ... please guide me how can i check that?

Answer (score 0):

Even if use target SDK below  23 it works on 6.0.in android only if you use min SDK 19 and if you run on device below API level 19 it won't but always higher versions support lower API levels through my knowledge, and be sure with your question.

Comment: I used like this.

`<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />`

It's work. 


`<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />`

When I change to targetSdkVersion to 23 then app show only white screen.

Comment: Ummm... build.gradle can use in only Android Studio. But I've ordered to use Eclipse. So Eclipse project have no build.gradle. That's why I've face with problem.

Comment: http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/03/changing-target-android-version-in-eclipse/